# Good example for using UIAlertControler

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

Im'm searching for good example of use UIAlertController with UISlider, UISegmentedControl, UIStepper.

I cant't use UIAlert and UIActionSheet also i don't know how to add slider, segmented control or stepper to AlertController and display this on UITableViewController.

I'm programming using swift.

Comment: There are plenty tutorials on UIAlertController and its customisation. You can't say you did not find anything by net surfing. Try to use those tutorials and write some code. Then also you face any problem then post your problems with errors here . This site is for resolving your problems, not for giving you ready made code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Hello", message: "Do you want to save changes?", preferredStyle: .Alert)


            let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "DON'T SAVE", style: .Default) { (action) in
                profileBack = "false"
                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
            }
            alertController.addAction(OKAction)

            let destroyAction = UIAlertAction(title: "SAVE", style: .Default) { (action) in
                self.callUpdateBasicDetailsApi()

            }
            alertController.addAction(destroyAction)

            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
                // ...
            }
```